# Magento - Persistent Shopping Cart not working

Tags: magento, session, cookies, cart, persistent

In my magento store (ce-1.9.0) I have turned on the persistent shopping cart option as i want to be able to keep items in guest basket for 2 weeks. I use the following settings:

System > Configuration > Persistent Shopping Cart

```
Enable Persistence : Yes
Persistence Lifetime (seconds) : 1209600 (2 weeks)
Enable Remember Me : No
Remember Me Default Value : Yes
Clear Persistence on Log Out : No
Persist Shopping Cart : Yes
```

Previously I was trying to set my cart to last for 1 day which i had the below cookie settings. These are still the same since turning persistent shopping cart on.

System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management

```
Cookie Lifetime : 86400 (1 day)
Cookie Path : (blank)
Cookie Domain : (blank)
Use HTTP Only : Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode : No
```

But my shopping carts are not being saved for the 2 weeks and clearing much quicker. Also when I inspect the database tables with what I imagine are the effected tables I can see:

```
persistent_session table is empty
```

sales_flat_quote has the order that I can see in my cart at the same time however the `is_persistent column` for that order and any since turning PCS on is `0` still.

Do I need to do anything else to activate this? Or are any of my settings stopping it from working?

Comment: The persistent shopping cart that is built-in to Magento only applies to logged-in customers but it sounds like you expect it to work for guests.

For guest cart persistence, you can give this module a shot: https://github.com/clockworkgeek/Magento-Guest-Cookies

Comment: Thanks, have added that module onto my store and it now works perfectly. I had misunderstood what the persistent cart did like you said